# Check for empty excel cell (Python)

Tags: python, excel

I understand there are similar questions but I don't quite understand their answers. Any help is appreciated.

```
import xlrd
path = ('E:\clean.xlsx')
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
is_empty = None
if (sheet.cell(row=0, column=0).value) == None:
    print("empty")
```

How do I check for a specific cell in my excel file and check if it is empty? Thanks.

Comment: TypeError: cell() got an unexpected keyword argument 'row' I am also getting this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the value using `sheet.cell_value(rowx=row, colx=col)`. However the sheet is an array. As a result the code will error if the value is null. Therefore you'll need to check the indexes are inside the array using `sheet.nrows` and `sheet.ncols`

I'm sure theres better way of checking null or empty. However the following should work: `if sheet.nrows > row and sheet.ncols > col and sheet.cell_value(rowx=row, colx=col):`

**Example:**

```
import xlrd
path = ('E:\clean.xlsx')

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

def is_null_or_empty(sheet, row, col):
    return True if sheet.nrows > row and sheet.ncols > col and sheet.cell_value(rowx=row, colx=col) else False
  
print(f'has value for row {0} col {0}: {is_null_or_empty(sheet, 0, 0)}')
print(f'has value for row {0} col {1}: {is_null_or_empty(sheet, 0, 1)}')
```

**Output:**

```
has value for row 0 col 0: False
has value for row 0 col 1: True
```